# EWS Managed API How can I distinct various appointments?

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, ews-managed-api

I have an app that uses appointment data from EWS and put that data into local database. The thing I need to do is that each appointment I have in that day, to add to database, and I need a unique identifier. Most of appointments are recurring ones, so I have a problem when using ItemId, because it is not unique then.

For those appointments, there I need to assign people later, and it doesn't have to mean that they will be the same, That's why, the changing of master appointment will not suffice.

Can someone help with this, how can I solve this? Is there some field that I can use as unique identifier?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the `ICalUid`, which is unique to the instance of the meeting, but is the same in every attendees calendar.

Another possibility would be to use the `CleanGlobalObjectId`, which I do not recommend in this case.